# TeX capacity exceeded even with \tikzexternalize

Tags: externalize

I'm trying to plot a set of 10000 points and I'm getting the `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].` error.
I'm using externalization.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage[arrowmos,european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
}   
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}

\newcommand*{\subb}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\supp}[1]{^{\mahtrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel=a,ylabel=b,width=\linewidth]% coordinates
            \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \addplot table[x index=0, y index=\i, col sep = comma] {data.csv};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And `data.csv` file is just a random set of 10000 points (later will be replaced with actual data).

Is there any solution? Or does TeX simply cannot handle that much data?

### Edit

---

Using a set of only 200 points the output is as expected:
[image]

Comment: Does it work with only some points? Could you please prodive an example data set with some points for compilation and testing?

Comment: It does work with 200 points. See edit.

Comment: externalize isn't going to help if you only have one tikzpicture as basically that tries to run each tikzpicture as a separate docuemnt and include them, but the generated separate document is going to be no simpler than the original docuemnt in this case.  Can the human reader see 10000 points?  Can you not sample the data using some external software prior to plotting?

Comment: Try lualatex? lualatex dynamically allocates memory and probably won't throw out of memory errors.

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle, this is what I'm going to do. Sample 500 or 1000 points.

Comment: with lualatex your document runs OK with a data file `c=0; while [ $c -le 10000 ] ; do let "c +=1"; echo "$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM"; done > data.csv` that is 10000 rows of 10 numbers (I commented out `%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}\tikzexternalize` )

Comment: Please stop torturing the dancing bear!

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer, more an extended comment**
An answer (use lualatex) was already given in the comment by Hood Chatham.

(But I think it's interesting enough to merit this.)

For plots with a lot of data points, marks have a huge influence on used memory. I tested this for a few marks with 500 points and 10 plots. Here are the results (as ASCII table):

```
option              data points     remark
                    500      250
                ----------------
[mark=none]     1170026   947012    approx. 0.87k/data point
[mark=square]   1268175
[mark=triangle] 1485689
[mark=diamond]  1614367
[mark=pentagon] 1743355
[mark=+]        1749165
[mark=x]        1749223
[](1)           2197715  1458330    approx. 2.89k/data point
[mark=star]     2351954
[mark=*]        2621674
[mark=o]        2621674
[mark=otimes]   3136768
[mark=ball](2) >3500000  3433143
----------
(1) default mix of marks (*, square*, otimes*, star, diamond*)
(2) TeX capacity exceeded
```

So if lualatex can't be used, doing such plots without marks would be a good idea. Or at least the marks should be selected carefully.

The data was generated similar to David Carlisles comment with

```
c=0; while [ $c -le 500 ] ; do echo "$c,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM,$RANDOM"; let "c +=1"; done > data-500.csv
```

And the tests were done with

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=a,ylabel=b,width=\linewidth]% coordinates
    \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
        \addplot+[] table[x index=0, y index=\i, col sep = comma] {data-500.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```